# Cordova build and run facing error variables.forEach is not a function

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic2

My ionic project suddenly doesn't response on any Cordova build/run command.

```
Macbooks-MBP:upost Kira$ cordova run ios
Error: variables.forEach is not a function
Macbooks-MBP:upost Kira$ cordova run android
Error: variables.forEach is not a function
Macbooks-MBP:upost Kira$ cordova build ios
Error: variables.forEach is not a function
Macbooks-MBP:upost Kira$ cordova build android
Error: variables.forEach is not a function
Macbooks-MBP:upost Kira$
```

here is the `Cordova -d build ios` response

```
Macbooks-MBP:upost Kira$ cordova -d build ios
No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't     been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
PlatformApi successfully found for platform ios
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Error: variables.forEach is not a function
```

Step I had tried:

1. Clone another new project
2. reinstall all node, npm, Cordova, ionic
3. Try in sample project, it works
4. Copy project from others, no working also
5. Remove/add Cordova platform for both iOS and android

Component version:

1. Cordova v7.0.1
2. ionic v3.5.0
3. node v6.11.1
4. npm v3.10.10

Comment: Where's your code? You have a syntax error.

Comment: @Darkrum which part of code I should show? is that configuration file having syntax error ?

Comment: Where ever variable.forEach is.

Comment: @Darkrum There is nothing related to `variables.forEach` inside project

Comment: That error says otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `ios-sim` under `platforms/cordova/node_modules/`

type command `npm i -g install ios-sim@latest`

and also `npm i -g install ios-deploy@latest`

then `Cordova build ios` or `Cordova run ios` will work